# Make IntelliJ IDEA use a different pom file for maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have a Maven project imported in IntelliJ IDEA. For technical reasons, we have two pom files - `pom.xml` and `pom-local.xml`.

I can use the alternative pom file manually using `mvn -f pom-local.xml install`. IDEA uses `pom.xml` but I can't find any option to change it to `pom-local.xml`. Any ideas how to make IDEA use the alternative pom file?

Comment: use profiles instead http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: we've tried that and it didn't work well. There were some issues with dependency conflicts. Although using different pom files is probably a temporary solution, it is what I'm stuck with for now.

Comment: If you have conflicts in your pom then you can use the Dependency exclusions https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html
and exclude the libraries that you want from your project for each profile.

Comment: Out of curirosity - what problem does this two-file approach solve?

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on how you define

> to make IDEA use the alternative pom file

Let's assume you want to run and debug your project with the alternative pom file. IntelliJ lets you provide all kind of parameters like you would do on a terminal. Just bring up the debug configuration via <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>F9</kbd>. Press the little '+' sign at the top left and select 'Maven'. In the 'Command line' input just provide `-f pom-local.xml test` or what ever goal you want to execute.